# Getting error while creating online meeting using graph api

Tags: azure, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Here i am using Microsoft graph api for creating online meeting events but after generating toke when i am requesting to create an online meeting i am getting this error
{
"error": {
"code": "ResourceNotFound",
"message": "User not found",
"innerError": {
"date": "2021-09-01T17:54:57",
"request-id": "fa773652-e824-4c9e-af05-085e249fb489",
"client-request-id": "fa773652-e824-4c9e-af05-085e249fb489"
}
}
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlWlk.png)

Comment: Are you sure the {{userId}} variable gets populated right? Did you checked the request (you will be able to see it in the console). Did you tried to hard code it once?

Comment: Yes i am using object id as a user id . i can't see any user id . i show a reference where they are using object id like user id

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello @AkashGupta,May I know if you have tried using Graph explorer for the same graph API call? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: @AkashGupta - We tried to repro this issue at our end and it is working fine for us. Could you please check if the userid that you are passing is valid using [Get a User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in graph explorer. 

[screenshot for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSSvF.png)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the So thread reference,

Use Delegated permissions to create an onlineMeeting

You must log in as a user, and you cannot use the client credential flow. You need to use the auth code flow to obtain the token.

[image]

Ref link - Delegated Permission: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

SO Reference: [404 error while creating Online Meeting using microsoft graph api c# without login into AzureActiveDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64043690/404-error-while-creating-online-meeting-using-microsoft-graph-api-c-sharp-withou)